# When exactly does MSSQL Trigger fires?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I've got a trigger

```
"ON [tbl_options] AFTER INSERT"
```

It inserts '1' to the [tbl_options].[comment]

Executing this query:

```
INSERT INTO [tbl_options] (key, value)
OUTPUT Inserted.comment
VALUES ('timeout','100');
```

Will give me NULL or '1'?

In other words: Does ON AFTER INSERT triger fires before returning OUTPUT or after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`msdn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

> Columns returned from OUTPUT reflect the data as it is after the
>   INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement has completed but before triggers
>   are executed.